Button on suggested edit popup doesn’t fit on mobile
Suggested edit popup has a button that doesn't fit into it. At the same time the entire popup width looks correct, based on the close icon position.



The issue probably arises due to different length of text on localized sites because it looks OK (in terms of width) on enSO:



Tested on Samsung S22 Android 14 Chrome browser
